# Xamarin external image not displaying problem

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to add images to Xamarin project on Visual Studio 2019. Images are displaying from local storage but external links. I need to be able display an image from an image url.

What i have trieds:

build app on android apis 27,28

check options for ssl implementation is Native TLS 1.2+

change the site ssl status http,https.

change the image and image urls from different sites.

another image extensions jpg,jpeg,png,...

change image sizes between 50 kb and 3mb.

When i uninstalled and rebuild the app, In first time run app throw this error:

```
Image Loading: Error getting stream for https://p-valid.com/images/logo.png:
System.ObjectDisposedException:
```

In my opinion, this error is a bug in Xamarin.

add this code to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Only way the image shows when I put the image to drawable folder then get it by its name:

```
var image = new Image { Source =  "test.jpg"};
```

My main code is:

```
var layout = new StackLayout { Padding = new Thickness(5, 10) };

var label = new Label { Text = "Hello world" };
var image = new Image { 
            Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://mydatabase/test.jpg"))
};

layout.Children.Add(label);
layout.Children.Add(image);

this.Content = layout;
```

What i expect from this code is:

Write Hello world and then show image

But its only showing Hello world and there is no image.

Also on debug output console writing this error:

```
ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid: Uri http://mydatabase/test.jpg
```

In my opinion, this code is about wrong cached image data.

Comment: is that url one that is accessible by your device?  Have you tested using the device's browser?  Does you app have internet permissions enabled?

Comment: My url is "p-valid.com/images/logo.png". 
Yes device is able to connect internet and this url. 
I tested from device's chrome browser. Also have code `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`  inside AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: that is not the correct permission - `android.permission.INTERNET`

Comment: @Turkuzolenedek After testing shared main code , it works in my project . Which 
is the version of VS and Xamarin Forms used .

Comment: It was the first setup in nuget packages on visual studio 2019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the start , the new created project about the version of xamarin forms is `4.2`. However , it occurs the error :

> [0:] ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid: Uri: https://aka.ms/campus.jpg

However after checking **the latest version of Xamarin Forms** in project . You can update it to the latest version :  **4.3.0.908675** to check whether it works .

Then the following code works in my local project:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var layout = new StackLayout { Padding = new Thickness(5, 10) };

        var label = new Label { Text = "Hello world" };
        var image = new Image
        {
            Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://s2.ax1x.com/2019/10/28/K6KUo9.png")),
            BackgroundColor = Color.Accent
        };

        layout.Children.Add(label);
        layout.Children.Add(image);

        Content = layout;
    }
}
```

The permission needs to be added in `manifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Effect :

[image]

**Note** : Better not loading large size of image. It also will results of error loading .

Comment: It's true, Xamarin 4.2 has this error and updating it solved the error.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms didn't load the external image which is from insecure site. I mean, http.

Comment: Loading secure site url(https) image works fine in Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the solution here: https://doumer.me/resolve-image-loading-error-in-xamarin-forms/

Right click on your android project

Select properties

Go to Android options

Click on the Advanced button

Change the HTTPClient to Managed

Change SSL/TLS implementation to Native TLS 1.2+

Save changes and run your project.

Images from Uri will load now